# Meu layout parou de funcionar

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu estou montando uma tela para um aplicativo android, fiz o layout da tela e estava funcionando, porém após atualizar o android studio meu layout não funciona mais.

O código pe esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".actyvities.MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    ></include>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Nova nota..."/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/insert_button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Inserir" />

</LinearLayout>-->

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Antes a tela ficava assim:

[image: Como o layout ficava antes:]

Mas agora ela fica assim:

[image: Como o layout fica agora:]

Não entendo muito de HTML, tentei arrumar o layout, mas só consegui colocando valores fixos no tamanho da caixa de texto, não queria fazer assim porque se mudar o tamanho da tela o layout não fica bom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, o layout Android não é HTML. É XML, que é um primo do HTML.

Brincadeiras a parte, o problema nesse caso é que está definindo a largura do `EditText` como `match_parent`, o que faz com ele sobreponha o `Button`.

O correto nesse caso é usar pesos (`layout_weight="1"`) em combinação com largura dinâmica (`layout_width="0dp"`), fazendo com que o `EditText` ocupe o máximo de largura disponível descontando a largura do botão. Isso é um truque muito comum no Android.

A parte importante do seu layout ficaria assim:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_box"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Nova nota..."/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/insert_button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Inserir" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Desculpe a confisão, layout nunca foi meu forte kkk Funcionou, muito abrigado.